# Specifying column alias with user-defined variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to rename the columns of a query by using user-defined variables.

For example:

```
select id as @rt from table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. You would have to create the sql string dynamically.

C#:

```cs
string columnName = "xy";
string sql = "SELECT id AS " + columnName + " FROM table_name";
```

VB:

```vb
Dim columnName As String = "xy"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT id AS " & columnName & " FROM table_name"
```

You can also do that in a stored procedure with MySql. See MySql documentation for [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

It would look something like this (not tested):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (columnName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT id AS ", columnName, " FROM table_name");
    PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE s1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
END$$
```

Comment: In an answer of this kind, one should hardly be afraid of saying too much about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). At least, it can do no harm to mention the possible risk thereof.

Comment: SQL injection sould not be a problem here, if the column names are defined by the programmer rather than entered by a user. In the latter case names would have to be tested for validity.