# Creating a column name alias from a select statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a column alias by looking up a value in another table. This is the MySQL I am trying but keep getting syntax errors - any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
product_code,
bField1 as (select [label_value] from [labels] where [field_value]='bField1'),
bField2 as (select [label_value] from [labels] where [field_value]='bField2'),
....
FROM products
```

Comment: It should be the other way around `<expression> as <alias>`

Comment: Are you sure that this is MySQL?

Comment: that is how the example code is written... it is the alias I am trying to make dynamic not the expression/field value

Comment: yes it is MySQL I am working in (via PHPRunner interface)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic column alias based on column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423572/dynamic-column-alias-based-on-column-value)

Comment: no it is different - that question was about using fixed values for the alias based on the field value, I am wanting to set the alias regardless of the field value

Comment: I don't think there's any way to create calculated aliases, except by writing dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

try as folow:

```
SELECT
product_code,
(select [label_value] from [labels] where [field_value]='bField1') as bField1,
(select [label_value] from [labels] where [field_value]='bField2') as bField2,
....
FROM products
```

Comment: I still want the column of bField1 returning just the column alias needs to be taken from another table. Are you saying the MySQL does it the opposite way round to SQL and that the alias comes before the column in the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

What you wish is not possible wtih only MySQL.

See below for similar questions:

[Dynamic column alias based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423572/dynamic-column-alias-based-on-column-value)

[Specifying column alias with user-defined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779168/specifying-column-alias-with-user-defined-variable)

I'm not sure why exactly you want to do this but it's always possible to incorporate the alias selection logic with the server side language that is dynamically creating the query. But of course, this would then be a two step process but you are not actually losing out as in your example you are using sub queries anyways.